# multi category drop down for multiple use in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Whether this drop down to the different categories. Such as supermarket, car showroom, hardware shop. I'll drop down to select from the supermarket which will be a new drop-down Visible vegetable Area, Area clothes, perfume Area. And when I do I select a new vegetable to be Visible drop down to the different vegetables. It also trains are similar. As the car company's car showroom to select drop-down to select Visible and company car model

Comment: Where's your question?

Comment: Are you telling us what you have created or asking a question because i'm not seeing the question in this post?

Comment: Actually I want drop down for multi category onchange behaviour .I want When I will select category list so onchange appear new drop down and when I will select category than appear new drop down of items list. .... sorry bro my English is very week but I done my best to explain what I required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know where is you question, you need put more info or litle code for help you, but for now i paste a `code` in [jsfidle](http://jsfiddle.net/fredthewebchap/maasz/), maybe it can help you

**Update** for next question you need explain with picture or something, well with Jquery and Bootstrap you can do a multilevel dropdown, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YXkUT/930/)

Comment: This should be in the comments section as this doesn't answer anything as this post doesn't have a question to be answered.

Comment: Actually I want drop down for multi category onchange behaviour .I want When I will select category list so onchange appear new drop down and when I will select category than appear new drop down of items list. .... sorry bro my English is very week but I done my best to explain what I required